# Displaying data in datatables - Laravel & PHP

Tags: php, laravel

This is how i fill my column using a normal html table which works fine

```
<td>

 <span class="status">
    @if ($try->status == 0)
        <span style="font-size:15px" class="label label-success">Fresh</span>

    @elseif ($try->status == 1)
        <span  style="font-size:15px" class="label label-danger">Stale</span>

    @else 
        <span  style="font-size:15px" class="label label-warning">Docked</span>
    @endif
    </span>

</td>
```

but now, i want to use a datatables for this and this is how i am doing it but it doesn't work. The column only appears blank although the response is returned from the database.

```
->addColumn('customer', function ($category) {
      return  '<p>'.$category->customers->name.'</p>';

   ->addColumn('status', function ($category) {
             '<p>
             @if ($category->status == 0)
             <span style="font-size:15px" class="label label-
                success">Fresh</span>

             @elseif ($category->status == 1)
             <span style="font-size:15px" class="label label-
               danger">Stale</span>
             @else
             <span style="font-size:15px" class="label label-
               warning">Docked</span>
            <p>';

          })->make(true);
```

PS: Customer's name appears in the `customer` column in the datatables but for `status` column, it is empty. Why is this happening with datatables? Could it be my syntax?

Comment: It would be better if you attach screenshot with this. BTW why is reason for using `addColumn` options in datatables

Comment: In 95% of the cases it's not correct to put HTML in a Database.

Comment: Blade is a template language that is compiled into PHP before it is seen by end-users.  You can't send blade in a variable in real time and expect PHP to handle it.

Comment: @Devon, send blade in a variable? I do not get what you mean by that please.  The `addColumn for customers` works fine and not the `status` addColumn.

Comment: You're using blade if statements in a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
You need to add return statement on status. and i have updated status code block bit clear.


->addColumn('customer', function ($category) {
    return  '<p>'.$category->customers->name.'</p>';        
}
->addColumn('status', function ($category) {

    $status = '<p>';
    if ($category->status == 0) {
        $status .= '<span style="font-size:15px" class="label label-success">Fresh</span>';
    }
    elseif ($category->status == 1) {
        $status .= '<span style="font-size:15px" class="label label-danger">Stale</span>';
    }
    else {
        $status .= '<span style="font-size:15px" class="label label-warning">Docked</span>';
    }
    $status .= '</p>';
    return $status;
})
->make(true);
```

Comment: @pravindabhi i am getting  `syntax error , unexpected '}'` on the last brace bracket for  `else if`

Comment: Okay figured out... please add add commas ';' to every span . Thank you and it worked